# WebRTC on Raspberry Pi without Browser

Tags: linux, node.js, audio, webrtc, peerjs

Is there anyway I can keep my Raspberry Pi connected to any WebRTC video chat room without using Browser. I am trying to build a IP camera with two way audio, where

one node will be raspberry pi + camera + mic + speaker which will join the WebRTC video chat room,

and the other node will be my phone

whenever needed I can open the chatroom from my phone and speak with the person on the other end if someone is present.

I tried using U4VL server WebRTC server http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/ but it doesn't send audio from my phone to the raspberry pi and the server get stuck after few minutes of usage.

Is there any way to build a server using nodejs, webrtc or something else which can be running the raspberry pi and opening that page can make me see the video and listen to the audio as well as my audio can be broadcasted on the speakers of raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used UV4L, both the Conference Web Page on the UV4L server and the Jitsi Meet front-end (a Web page on the same server). It worked flawlessly, but the video resolution is not very high in Jitsi Meet, although the audio quality is very good.

Comment: By using Jitsi Meet, were you able to send audio from other end to raspberry pi audio output?

Comment: two-way audio is supported: http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/article.php?storyid=182

Comment: two-way video is also supported: http://www.linux-projects.org/downloads/screenshots/webrtc-twoway.png

Comment: what server did you use for the jitsi-meet client front end? do I need a seperate server instance? or how do I go about starting the application, there is no jitsimeet server for arm architecture yet

Comment: @strumps the question was for you

Answer (score 0):

Without using a browser, perhaps the best option is to use [FreeSWITCH](https://freeswitch.org/).  There has been a lot of work on the master branch to add improved video support and has native support for WebRTC.  The demos I've seen use static video content for connections coming from WebRTC, but I suspect it should be possible to use a video stream coming from an attached device.  FreeSWITCH can also host the conference room, though obviously the limited processing power of the Raspberry Pi will be a factor. You can always run a second FreeSWITCH instance elsewhere with more CPU power.

FreeSWITCH has a feature called [Verto](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_verto) and the sources include a good [demo app](https://webrtc.freeswitch.org/verto/index.html#page-main) that should get you most of the way toward making the connection from your phone into FreeSWITCH.

It's worth mentioning here that while recent versions of Android support WebRTC in the browser natively, for iOS you'll still need a custom app of some kind. If you do decide to build something for iOS, check out [this Cordova plugin](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc).